# Intended Mondegreens?

Tags: lyrics

I could swear Lloyd Cole is constantly tricking his audience to mishear his lyrics ("So You Like To Save The World", "Blue Like Mars", to name just two candidate songs), but of course I have no proof and I am not the right person to judge anyway (I'm a German).

An *almost* example would be the Sex Pistols, who were fond of the word "country" and pronounced it so you get the "right" idea, but I wouldn't file that under intentional *mis*hearing, but as intentional also-hearing (?) or whatever you may call it.

Neither do "Something Something Leonard Bernstein" style lyrics fall under this, which you can't (shan't?) understand at all.

Thus: Do you have a "Word of God" example (maybe it was revealed in an interview) of a band/a singer intentionally creating potential mondegreens for trolling the audience or whatnot?